# 冷蔵庫が壊れたので、新しいのを買うことにした。

Tags: meaning

1 - 冷蔵庫が壊れたので、新しいのを買うことにした。
2 - 私は部屋を綺麗にした。

Can Someone explain the difference between ~ことにする vs ~にする・~くする

1 is I decided to buy a new fridge
2 is I cleaned my room

They look the same to me, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

ことにする means *to decide*.

- [【JLPT N4】文法・例文：〜ことにする](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/04/29/jlptn4-grammar-kotonisuru/#:%7E:text=%E6%96%87%E5%9E%8B%EF%BC%9A%E3%80%9C%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B,-%5B%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%5D&text=%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AE%E6%84%8F%E5%BF%97%E3%81%A7%E3%80%9C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B,%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%E3%80%82&text=Used%20to%20say%20that%20you,something%20of%20your%20own%20volition.&text=%E3%83%BB%E5%B0%91%E3%81%97%E7%A1%AC%E3%81%84%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%AB%E3%80%8C%E3%80%9C,%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82)

～にする can mean *to decide*/*to make (sth) ～*

- [【JLPT N4】文法・例文：〜にする](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/05/29/jlptn4-grammar-nisuru/)
- [【Ｎ５文法】～にする／くする](https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=20162)

A rule of thumb: When the preceding word is a stem of na-adjective (such as 綺麗), it means the latter; Otherwise, it means *to decide*.